# SQL Server Transpose Rows Into New Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks like the below. There's a unique ID that I'm generating, two other IDs that reference other tables (ArgumentIDs and eventID), a categorization type (eQualType), and then values associated with the eventID and eQualType.

There's actually 20 different Value columns (shortened for this example) with the vast majority of rows only having something in Value1. The others will have a number in 16-20 of the columns (all rows associated with a given event and eQualType 1-5 will have the same number of columns filled in).

I am trying to get the below table to pivot...

```
UniqueID ArgumentIDs eventID eQualType Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 
1              7       1         4       1      2      3      4 
2              10      1         7       23         
3              11      1         2       1      2      2      3
4              15      1         3       1      33     2      31
5              8       1         6       8          
6              3       1         1       105    106    107    108
7              9       1         5       0      0      0      0
8              12      2         4       1      2      3      4
9              16      2         1       91     92     93     94
10             19      2         2       1      2      2      3
11             17      2         5       0      0      0      0
12             4       2         3       12     3      2      4
```

Into something like the below in a separate table (ideally would insert into that table which already contains data in this format). The ArgumentIDs would have to be a placeholder or a blank given that it wouldn't reference anything in another table, and the eQualType would have to be a new value that doesn't match any of the previous ones.

```
UniqueID ArgumentIDs eventID eQualType Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5
1            x          1       999      105     1      1      1      0
2            x          1       999      106     2      33     2      0
3            x          1       999      107     2      2      3      0
4            x          1       999      108     3      31     4      0
5            8          1       6        8
```

I don't know if this is possible or if it's better to do as a transformation before even loading into SQL.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get the table to pivot"? How do you calculate the the `Value` columns in the result from the values contained in the base table? It looks like aggregating the value columns and add them as new columns to a result table...

Comment: The Value1 column in the result table is row 6 from the base table, Value2 is row 3, etc.

Comment: Essentially the rows in the base table are being transposed into columns in the results table, clustered together by the eventID

Comment: OK, you want to transpose the value columns of the input into different result rows (one row per value column) and add another result "value" column per row with the same  eventID. I think you should update your question and rename the value column names of the result table e. g. into "Row1Value", "Row2Value" etc. and complete the example result to explain the processing logic of the input rows #2 und #5 (#2 does not appear, the handling of #5 is surprising). I think you can achieve your goal by two or three `pivot`/`unpivot` functions with the right filters...

Comment: @RYoda Sounds like OP actually wants to `UNPIVOT`, not pivot.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I figured it out. See below for the code.

```
INSERT INTO Results (eventID,Result1,Result2,Result3,Result4,Result5)
SELECT eventID, [1] as Result1, [2] as Result2, [3] as Result3, [4] as Result4, [5] as Result5
FROM
(SELECT [inputTable].eventID,[inputTable].eQualType,[inputTable].Value1
FROM eventQData
WHERE eQualType IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND (Value2 > 0)
) AS inputTable
PIVOT
(MAX(Value1)
FOR [eQualType] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
```

Comment: I can understand OP accepting his/her own answer because there's only one person who could actually test this given the incomplete sample input/output data in the question. But why the upvote? This doesn't answer the question. It applies unstated rules. It is syntactically incorrect. And even after fixing the errors, it comes nowhere near producing the stated desired output.

Comment: Well, answering the own question with an open bounty before the bounty dead line is over and without answering all parts of the question seems indeed a little bit unsporting. I think Craig's answer is nearer at what was questioned and should be honored as such by accepting it (especially if you look at the time he spent to find the non-trivial answer).

Answer (score 14):

When you take columns `Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4` and transpose them into rows:

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
Value4
```

What you're actually doing is called `UNPIVOT`ing (not pivoting). This has created some confusion around your question. But noting this helps find a fairly straight-forward solution. (Of course you it turns out you do want to re`PIVOT` your intermediate results into your final solution. So that still applies.)

The query below performs an UNPIVOT which is used as a subquery in the PIVOT query. I found it easy to keep track of the original Value column that each Result value came from; and you can note this by subtracting 100 from `eQualType` in the final results. My answer also demonstrates the effect of including a `Result6` column in the final output. (Of course it can be excluded if not needed.)

```
SELECT  eventID, 100 + ValueCol as eQualType,
        [1] as Result1, [2] as Result2, [3] as Result3, [4] as Result4, [5] as Result5, [6] as Result6
FROM (
        SELECT eventId, eQualType, CAST(RIGHT(ValueCol, 1) as int) as ValueCol, val
        FROM (  SELECT  eventId, eQualType, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4
                FROM    @t1) src
        UNPIVOT (val FOR ValueCol IN (Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4)
                ) AS unpvt
    )as inp
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR eQualType in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) pvt
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Here are the results using your sample input data (UniqueID and ArgumentID excluded based on information in your question):

```
eventID     eQualType   Result1     Result2     Result3     Result4     Result5     Result6
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           101         105         1           1           1           0           8
1           102         106         2           33          2           0           NULL
1           103         107         2           2           3           0           NULL
1           104         108         3           31          4           0           NULL
2           101         91          1           12          1           0           NULL
2           102         92          2           3           2           0           NULL
2           103         93          2           2           3           0           NULL
2           104         94          3           4           4           0           NULL

(8 row(s) affected)
```

Note that my results match most of your sample output apart from the nonsensical row 5 you included. And of course I've included results for `eventID=2` and well as `Result6`.